# Blank value is getting passed to Database when importing data from Excel to SQL Server using VBScript

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript

I am trying to develop a vbs to import data from excel to sql server.
Byte values are getting imported but in varchar field of DB, string values from Excel are not getting imported (the field is empty). below is code

```
Option Explicit

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
dim strSqlInsertString,objConnection2,objRecordSet2
dim objExcel,objWorkBook,strRow

Set objConnection2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection2.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=appapollo;Password=dna;Initial Catalog=6057;Data Source=lxi282"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("D:\Cardiopacs\Automation\Forward\test.xls")

strRow = 2

dim AEName,AEDescription,AEIPAddress,AEPort,ModifiedDate,QRSSApplicationEntityID,MobileAE,NotificationXML,PreFetch,PreFetchSuffix


strSqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO SSDICOMApplicationEntities (AEName,AEDescription,AEIPAddress,AEPort,ModifiedDate,QRSSApplicationEntityID,MobileAE," & _
"NotificationXML,PreFetch,PreFetchSuffix) " & _
"VALUES('" &AEName& "','" &AEDescription& "','" &AEIPAddress& "','" &AEPort& "','" &ModifiedDate& "','" &QRSSApplicationEntityID& "','" &MobileAE& "'," & _
"'" &NotificationXML& "','" &PreFetch& "','" &PreFetchSuffix& "')"

Do Until objExcel.Cells(strRow,1).Value = ""

    'SSDIOMApplicationEntityID = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    AEName = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 1).Value
    AEDescription = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 2).Value
    AEIPAddress = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 3).Value
    AEPort = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 4).Value
    ModifiedDate = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 5).Value
    QRSSApplicationEntityID = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 6).Value
    MobileAE = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 7).Value
    NotificationXML = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 8).Value
    PreFetch = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 9).Value
    PreFetchSuffix = objExcel.Cells(strRow, 10).Value
    strRow = strRow + 1



set objRecordSet2=objConnection2.execute(strSQLInsertString)

loop

objconnection2.close

set objConnection2 = Nothing


objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: doesn't the OLE DB Provide for Excel only check the first 8 records to determine the datatype of a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that what your code does is

```
generate sql command with empty values
do until end
    retrieve values from excel
    execute sql command with empty values
loop
```

And what it should do is

```
do until end
    retrieve values from excel
    generate the new sql command from the retrieved values
    execute the new generated sql command
loop
```

Comment: Yep. Move `strSqlInsertString` inside your loop, before your `Execute()` command and you'll have better results. On a side note... `strRow`? Why not `intRow`? :)